# New SSL Cert causes no connection to website on POST from web application

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I have a web application which will not connect to a website to POST after they changed their SSL cert. The URL and REF post is mentioned below.

Is there anything else I should try on the server?

```
https://www.vancodev.com/cgi-bin/wstest2.vp (test)
https://www.vancoservices.com/cgi-bin/ws2.vps (production)
```

I have the certs added:
[image]

However, the application still fails to connect. If I add code to my web app to ignore certs, it works fine.

Ideas?

REF CODE POST: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391756/does-changing-ssl-cert-on-a-server-break-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a CRL on the certificate? Can your application server reach the new CRL? Check the "CRL Distribution Points" field in the cert and there should be a URL. Try to browse to that URL from your application server.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing their "GeoTrust DV SSL CA" root CA certificate from your Intermediate Certification Authorities store.

https://ssltools.geotrust.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp

[image]

Comment: Thanks Greg. Is the download link there for the DV SSL CA?

Comment: I don't know, but if you can view the cert in question you can probably save it off somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem and found this Question. I was using Letsencrypt on Nginx and needed this for my SSL settings:

```
ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem;
```

I was using `ssl_certificate`...`cert.pem` in those settings, and that was the problem.